# Can't seem to log into my Yahoo OpenID account

Tags: support, specific-question, openid, login

Hi, My account is:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143317/erik

and I can't seem to log in. I recall associating it with my SO account:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/221745/erik

which logs in just fine. I've tried the various openID providers I have (google, yahoo) but I must have used something I don't recall. My own fault for clearing cookies/history/etc. Whups.

any help?

also: when I try to log into meta with my yahoo ID - which I think is the one the account has, I get the following:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

### ( edit )

I managed to figure out my openID URL - but I still can't log in with it. When I try it says:

> The following required parameters were
>   missing from the
>   PositiveAssertionResponse message:
>   dnoa.op_endpoint

Comment: Go go appspot in this case.

Comment: I'm having the same problem from France, on May 23rd.
Fortunately, one of my browsers was still logged to stackoverflow, so that I could add a different OpenId provider to my account.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo had misconfigured servers in their server farm, and it was causing intermittent Yahoo openid failures.

This is confirmed.

In general you should mail via the address at the bottom of the page for per-user specific login help, or use the **I forgot my login information** link in the login page to get it mailed to you automatically.

(as for your meta account, you are using the rogue unsupported "fake" openid.appspot provider -- I highly recommend switching away from that.)

Comment: I'd love to switch it to my google, but I can't figure out how to log in WITH it first. I didn't even know what I'd used. And for the life of my I can't figure out which email address I used :-\

Comment: Okay, I've seemed to managed to log in to the 'fake open ID provider' and figure out my openID url is `http://openid-provider.appspot.com/wurzer.design`  but when I attempt to log in via that URL, it returns an error, which I now included in the orignal post

Comment: FYI the Yahoo problems are still ongoing as far as I know :(

Comment: have you found that their problems are increasing? I've been unable to login to ServerFault for hours now. I'm going to suffer serious withdrawal if this isn't fixed before my StackOverflow login times out.