# Unable to login to stackoverflow.com using Yahoo openid

Tags: support, openid, login, yahoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t seem to log into my Yahoo OpenID account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49113/cant-seem-to-log-into-my-yahoo-openid-account)

I'm unable to login to stackoverflow.com using Yahoo openid. When I click Yahoo logo on https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate I get a message:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
No OpenID endpoint found.
```

Logging in to other SO sites using Yahoo works — I've tried meta and serverfault. Tested with Firefox 3.6.3 and Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 0):

I can repro. Let me look into it.

edit: intermittent. I can get in sometimes via Yahoo, othertimes I can't. Same [Yahoo server farm error issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49113/cant-seem-to-log-into-my-yahoo-openid-account/49223#49223) as before... closing as dupe.

Comment: The error message was different, so I assumed this is different. I've tried at least 10 times - and failed every time.

Comment: @tom I was able to repro once, then the second time it worked. This is highly symptomatic of "bad server farm" issues that we knew about